# How can I get the path of the project where my custom control will added to?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, visual-studio-2022

I am working on a **custom control** and I am trying to find a way to **get** the **path** of the **project** where my custom control **will added to**... Not the one where I am making it.

The reason is because I want to add some **strings** from my **custom control** into **embedded Resources.resx** file of the **project** where my **custom control** will **added to**.

Here is an example of my code...

```
public class SVGEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    private OpenFileDialog open_file_dialog = null;

    protected virtual void InitializeDialog(OpenFileDialog open_file_dialog)
    {
        open_file_dialog.Title = "Select an SVG File: ";
        open_file_dialog.Filter = "SVG File (*.svg)|*.svg";
    }

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        if (provider is null || provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) is null)
        {
            return value;
        }

        Control ctrl = (Control)context.Instance;

        if (open_file_dialog is null)
        {
            open_file_dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            InitializeDialog(open_file_dialog);
        }

        if (value is string s) open_file_dialog.FileName = s;

        if (open_file_dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ctrl.Select();
            ctrl.Capture = true;

            //[ The path of .resx file. ]
/* ---> */  string resx_file_path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Properties\\Resources.resx";

            //[ Generates resource's name by filename. ]
            string resource_name = Path.GetFileName(open_file_dialog.FileName);

            //[ Converts file's XmlDocument to string. ]
            XmlDocument xml_document = new XmlDocument { XmlResolver = null };
            xml_document.Load(open_file_dialog.FileName);
            string svg_image_document = xml_document.InnerXml;

            //[ Adds resource to .resx file. ]
            Helpers.ResourcesOperator.Add_or_Update_Resource(resource_name, svg_image_document, resx_file_path);

            //[ Returns only the name of resource. ]
            return resource_name;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

My "problem" located at the place where `--->` is. I tried using `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and some other stuff I found in stackoverflow, but with no luck. When I place my control to another project I get a message that could not find this path.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: If you are debugging the application in visual studio, `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will be the `Project\bin\Debug` folder.  But if you are just running the .exe somewhere else, it will be wherever you are running it from. `AppContext.BaseDirectory` gets the directory that the .exe file is running from but that doesn't help too much.  Also, its probably best practice to use `Path.Combine()` instead of using the `+` on paths.

Comment: [CodeDomSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializer) => [SerializeToResourceExpression()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializerbase.serializetoresourceexpression) / [SerializeResource()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializerbase.serializeresource) -- Decorate the class with `[DesignerSerializer(typeof([Your Derived Type]), typeof(CodeDomSerializer))]`

Comment: Ahm, sorry? Anyway (if you're still there), the UITypeEditor is unrelated to the task, you have to handle serialization through [IDesignerSerializationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.idesignerserializationmanager)

Comment: @Jimi: Is this also has to do with how I'll get the path of the .resx file? Or is it something that you notice that I should do anyway? Regardless of what I'm asking I mean...

Comment: You don't need the path of anything, that's not something a Custom Control needs or can know. The CodeDomSerializerBase (`IDesignerSerializationManager`) is meant to handle this, both for the Invariant culture and the current UI Culture, if the application is localizable

Comment: Hmmm... And how I'll point to the .resx file I want?

Comment: You don't, that's not something you can handle. How is a Custom Control supposed to know about the structure of a *Project*, which is a Visual Studio *concept*? You need to implement `ISupportInitialize` and let the CodeDomSerializerBase your custom serializer derives from do the job

Comment: As I told you to a previous question I made, I have to study all this really harder!!! I think I miss a very important piece... Thank you very much for your time and really sorry that I spent it like this!!! :)